# In Perl, can I dynamically add methods to only one object of a package?

Tags: perl, monkeypatching, www-mechanize

I'm working with [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to automate web-based back office clicking I need to do to get my test e-commerce orders into the state I need them to be to test changes I have made to a particular part of a long, multi-part workflow. To process a lot of orders in a batch, I need to click the `Home` link often. To make that shorter, I hacked a method into `WWW::Mechanize` at run time like this (based on an example in *Mastering Perl* by brian d foy):

```
{ # Shortcut to go back to the home page by calling $mech->go_home
  # I know I'll get a warning and do not want it!
  no warnings 'once';
  my $homeLink = $mech->find_link( text => 'Home' )->url_abs();
  $homeLink =~ s/system=0/system=1/;
  *WWW::Mechanize::go_home = sub {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->get($homeLink);
  };
}
```

This works great, and does not hurt anyone because the script I'm using it in is only used by me and is not part of the larger system.

But now I wonder if it is possible to actually only tell one `$mech` object that is has this method, while another `WWW::Mechanize` object that might be created later (to, say, do some cross-referencing without mixing up the other one that has an active session to my back office) cannot use that method.

I'm not sure if that is possible at all, since, if I understand the way objects work in Perl, the `->` operator tells it to look for the subroutine `go_home` inside the package `WWW::Mechanize` and pass the `$mech` as the first argument to it. Please correct me if this understanding is wrong.

I've experimented by adding a sort of hard-coded check that only lets the original `$mech` object use the function.

```
my $onlyThisMechMayAccessThisMethod = "$mech";
my $homeLink = $mech->find_link( text => 'Home' )->url_abs();
$homeLink =~ s/system=0/system=1/;
*WWW::Mechanize::go_home = sub {
  my ($self) = @_;
  return undef unless $self eq $onlyThisMechMayAccessThisMethod;
  return $self->get($homeLink);
};
```

Since `"$mech"` contains the address of where the data is stored (e.g. `WWW::Mechanize=HASH(0x2fa25e8)`), another object will look differently when stringified this way.

I am not convinced however that this is the way to go. So my question is: **Is there a better way to only let one object of the `WWW::Mechanize` class have this method?** I'm also glad about other suggestions regarding this code.

Comment: Why don't you subclass WWW::Mechanize and instantiate that subclass for those instances that need the additional method?

Comment: Or better, write a WWW::Mechanize::Pluggable plugin that wraps new() so that you can specify at instantiation that the additional feature should be available for that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just

```
$mech->follow_link(text => 'Home')
```

and I don't think it's special enough to warrant a method of its own, or to need restricting to an exclusive club of objects.

It's also worth noting that there is no need to mess with typeglobs to declare a subroutine in a different package. You just have to write, for example

```
sub WWW::Mechanize::go_home {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->get($homeLink);
};
```

But the general solution is to subclass [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) and declare as members only those objects you want to have the new method.

---

File `MyMechanize.pm`

```
package MyMechanize;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'WWW::Mechanize';

sub go_home {
  my $self = shift;
  my $homeLink = $self->find_link(text => 'Home')->url_abs;
  $homeLink =~ s/system=0/system=1/;
  return $self->get($homeLink);
}

1;
```

File `test.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyMechanize;

my $mech = MyMechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://mydomain.com/path/to/site/page.html')
$mech->go_home;
```

Comment: @daxim: can you explain your preference of `use parent`? If you choose to go this way then the preceding `use WWW::Mechanize` is superfluous.

Comment: `parent` should be preferred because it's at BEGIN time. You are correct, it already loads the module named in the import list.

Comment: @daxim: got it. It's also more expressive. You've converted me.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the long explanation. I'll try that today. Re the home link, it is not just a `$mech->follow_link(text => 'Home')
` because not every page has that link (which sucks) and there are two states of the param `system` that switch according to the sub-area I'm in, but I always need it to be `1`.

Comment: @simbabque: in that sense `follow_link` is more useful as it returns `undef` if the specified link isn't found and doesn't attempt the `get`.

Comment: That's why I wanted to use `get`. I still want the browser to go to that page because I need it to start the next step in my workflow. Thus, I created a shortcut to call it whether the link is there or not.